# Return two the principal layout with edited edit text with an object (android)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-edittext

I m new to android environment  i m creating a sign up  activity that include two layouts , the first layout contain editTexts to fill information and the second contain a return button to the first page 
i want when i return to the previous first page to contain the last info 
so i Initialize an object contains the info's but when I do 
editTextNAme.setText(user.getName); it doesn't work even if the user is not null at all

```
 private void replaceParam() {
        Toast.makeText(InscriptionActivity.this,"user "+user.getNom() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setStr(nom,user.getNom());
         setStr(prenom,user.getNom()) ;
         setStr(email,user.getEmail());
        setStr(telephone,user.getEmail());
        Toast.makeText(InscriptionActivity.this,"user "+user.getPrenom() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void setStr(EditText editText,String string) {
        editText.setText(string);


    }




    public void back(View view) {

        setContentView(R.layout.inscription1);
replaceParam();


    }

    public void forward(View view) {
      createUser();
    }

    public void  createUser(){
        Object[] object =userService.message(getStr(telephone),getStr(password1),getStr(password2));
        String message = (String) object[1];
        int   result = (int) object[0];
        if(result==1){
            injectParam();
            Toast.makeText(InscriptionActivity.this,message , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.inscription2);


        }else{
            clear(result);
            Toast.makeText(InscriptionActivity.this,message , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }



    }
```

thanks  , im really glad to be a part of stack overFlow

Comment: show us your first page and second page code.

Comment: To be honest, my eyes are painful with this kind of indentation, please reformat it. And we need the code from 2 activities, show the way you start, receive params between them.

Comment: can i have someone emails .